# Specflow test results accessible from AfterScenario hook?

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

Is there any way to access the test results (success/fail, maybe even asserts, etc) from a Specflow AfterScenario hook?  I don't see anything, but it seems like something that would be included.

Answer (score 4):

You can get hold of the test result by peeking into the ScenarioContext.Current. There's a TestError property that may help you.

See this wiki (https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, but you need to use reflection. In your [AfterScenario] block use the following:

```
PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(ScenarioContext).GetProperty("TestStatus", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
MethodInfo getter = pInfo.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
object TestResult = getter.Invoke(ScenarioContext.Current, null);
```

TestResult will be OK, MissingStepDefinition etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use ScenarioContext to do this.  Here is some example code which hopefully makes sense (doesn't get the actual assert value - not possible as far as I know), but does mean I can leave the browser open if the test fails:

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario() {
if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError == null) {
   // Test failed (use ScenarioContext.Current.TestError to print out error to logs if required)
   _driver.Quit
  }
}
```